# Does it force heap allocation?

Tags: c++

Generally, 99,9% of the time (AFAIK), the following object initialization:

```
MyClass myObject(5);
```

or equivalently

```
MyClass myObject = MyClass(5);
```

will cause myObject to be created on stack.

However, if in the following line `myObject` was passed to a function, like this:

```
myFunction(&myObject)
```

it wouldn't cause an error, instead the object would be magically allocated on the heap. Is that true or am I missing something?

Comment: _"Is that true or am I missing something?"_ A basic c++ introductory book probably. Nothing of what you're showing has to do with heap (dynamic storage) allocation.

Comment: Nothing is ever "magically" allocated on the heap in C++ unless you deem it so with new.

Comment: That is incorrect. Need to use new to put stuff on the heap. Some templates and classes do this for ypu

Comment: "&myObject" passes the address of the object to the called function(myFunction here). After the function call returns, any changes made to the object will be reflected in the calling function.

Comment: Basically; pointers doesn't always point to the heap, they can point to the stack as well.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello: That's a bit strong. Exceptions may very well be "magically" allocated on the heap. But in those cases `catch` will apply the inverse magic to take them off the heap.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not true. Nothing magical happens here:

```
myFunction(&myObject)
```

That is just taking the address of `myObject`, on the stack (if that is indeed where it is), and passing that address to `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> However, if in the following line myObject was passed to a function, like this:
>
> ```
> myFunction(&myObject)
> ```
>
> it wouldn't cause an error, instead the object would be magically allocated on the heap. Is that true or am I missing something?

That is not correct. The call

```
myFunction(&myObject)
```

will simply use the address of `myObject`, which is an object on the stack, to call `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

The call of your function would cause an error or not will depend on the definition of your function. It does not relate to your object located at heap or stack.
In here, you pass an address of myObject into your function, your function need have parameter passed by pointer, something like below:

```
myFunction(MyClass* myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
int * foo ()
{
    int x = 0;
    return x;
}
```

Because `x` is allocated on the stack, when `foo` finishes, it goes out of scope, and no magic happens, just undefined behavior that will generally lead to a core dump

Heap allocation requires calling `new` (except for placement `new`)